# C# - Get JavaScript variable value using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, javascript

I currently have 2 JavaScript variables in which I need to retrieve values from.  The HTML consists of a series of nested DIVs with no id/name attributes.  Is it possible to retrieve the data from these variables using HTMLAgilityPack?  If so how would I go about doing so, if not what would be required, regular expressions?  If the latter, please help me in creating a regular expression that would allow me to do this.  Thank you.

```
<div style="margin: 12px 0px;" align="left">
<script type="text/javascript">
variable1 = "var1";
variable2 = "var2";
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not so sure it will be easy to do in general.  Sure HTML Agility Pack can help you find the right elements in the HTML, but then you'd have to parse the javscript and that would require another parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to scrape this information from a website? Most likely one you don't have direct control over? There are several ways to do this, I'll go easy to hard( at least as I see em):

1. Ask the owner (of the site). Most of the time they can give you direct access to the information and if you ask nicely, they might just let you have it for free
2. You can use the [webBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control, run the javascript and then parse values from the DOM afterwards. As opposed to HttpWebRequest, this allows for all the proper values to be loaded on the page and scraped. [Helpful Link Here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290341%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
3. Steal the source with [Firebug.](http://getfirebug.com/) Inspect the website with Firebug to see which URLs are called from the background. Most likely, its using an asynchronous request to retrieving the updated information from a webservice. Using Firebug, you can view this under the NET -> XHR. Look at the request and the values returned, you can then retrieve the values your self and parse the contents from the source rather than scrape the page.

I think this might be the information you were looking for, but if not let me know and I can clarify/fix answer